# Why are these inherited types used as parameterized types incompatible types?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, collections

I understand with parameterized collections that if you want to use subtypes of the parameterized type, you need to declare the collection as `Collection<? extends Whatever>`

For instance:

```
public interface Fruit {}
public interface Banana extends Fruit {}

void thisWorksFine() {
  //Collection<Fruit> fruits;          //wrong
  Collection<? extends Fruit> fruits;  //right
  Collection<Banana> bananas = new ArrayList<>();
  fruits = bananas;
}
```

But if I add an extra layer, this blows up:

```
public interface Box<T> {}

void thisDoesNotCompile() {
    Collection<Box<? extends Fruit>> boxes;
    Collection<Box<Banana>> bananaBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
    boxes = bananaBoxes;  // error!
}
```

with the error:

```
error: incompatible types
required: Collection<Box<? extends Fruit>>
found:    Collection<Box<Banana>>
```

Why are these incompatible?  Is there any way to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you can add a `Box<Apple>` to `boxes`, which would violate the integrity of `bananaBoxes`.

```
public interface Apple extends Fruit {}

//...

Box<Apple> apples = new Box<>(); // this is legal
Box<? extends Fruit> fruits = apples; // this is legal

Collection<Box<Banana>> bananaBoxes = new ArrayList<>(); 

Collection<Box<? extends Fruit>> boxes = bananaBoxes; //if this were legal...
boxes.add(fruits); //then this would be legal

//and this would be a type violation:
Box<Banana> bananas = bananaBoxes.iterator().next();
```

You could instead do

```
Collection<? extends Box<? extends Fruit>> boxes = bananaBoxes;
```

which is legal since it prevents the above case.